# Multistep forecasting using a model trained on forecast data

Tags: time-series, forecasting

Usually when making a time series model the training data is prepared in a format akin to:

| TimeStamp | Actual |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-07 00:00 | 80 |
| 2023-01-07 01:00 | 110 |
| 2023-01-07 02:00 | 115 |
| 2023-01-07 03:00 | 95 |
| ... |  |

That is for each time stamp we have some actual values (for the outcome and any additional variables). But then, when making forecasts, we use forecast data (of these same variables) since actual data is not available. So wouldn't it make more sense to use forecast data when training the model as this is what the model will be using during forecasting? So a format more akin to:

| TickDate | TimeStamp | Horizon (hours) | Forecast | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-07 00:00 | 168 | 100 | 80 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-07 01:00 | 169 | 90 | 80 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-07 00:00 | 144 | 130 | 110 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-07 01:00 | 145 | 115 | 110 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

In this case the time stamps are repeated multiple times with the same actual, but with different forecasts for each time we made a forecast (TickDate) for this time stamp.

This structure essentially holds the same information for the outcome (but not for the variables) so it might work just as well if not better than the first option. Additionally if we are making multistep forecasts we can include all of these for each TickDate and have a model which can make multistep forecasts directly.

Does this makes sense? When I've tried this approach on a problem the second structure performed much worse than the first option, and I am wondering if I am missing something, as to why the first option is much more prevalent in the literature. I should also mention that I've tried this approach on a couple of machine learning models and not time series models (ARIMA et al.), which do (maybe) require data as in the first table.